# Safari Browser Tracking

Tags: macos, safari

I live in England and frequently use www.booking.com.  I am on holiday in Portugal using a 3G hot spot.  I launched Safari and went to booking.com and it presented me with a page in Portuguese.  I changed the language to English.

I then disconnected from wifi, cleared the Safari cookies, history and emptied the cache.  When I returned to booking.com it presented me with a page in English and said "Welcome Back".

My question is how does it know me.  Is there any information stored on my computer that I don't know about and which is available to the website?

Comment: This may be an example of a situation in which it would be helpful to use a VPN service that gives you a public IP address associated with your home country: websites that localize based on the visitor's IP address with then perform as you're accustomed to back home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens all the time :

- The website initially guessed your location by the fact that your IP address
  indicated you are in Portugal.
- You then changed to English
- You scrubbed out all browser data
- When you reconnected, it remembered the language preference, again by IP address.

Since you probably share the same IP address as everybody else on the 3G hotspot,
others connecting through it may find themselves on the English page if they go on 
booking.com.
The website may forget your IP after some time has passed without connections.

If you are using a public hotspot, you should be very careful.
Never type credit-card numbers or login to your bank on such a network.